# loading old web pages and not the updated ones

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, cache, uploading

I have updated my design and uploaded it to my server, but it's showing old content for sometime, new content for sometime. I randomly checked lots of computer, same problem is happening everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to provide a definitive answer here due to a shortage of information provided. Perhaps you could provide additional detail in future or a link showing what is happening.

Here are some things you could try:

- Try clearing the cache on individual machines
- Try clearing cache on the server side
- Check that any files that you were expecting to be updated during the
  upload actually updated i.e. check that upload was successful or if
  error message was displayed.